# ValidationError: Cast to ObjectID failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to add a value to an array using Mongoose and Express.

```
router.put( '/projectUser/:id', function( req, res ) {
    return ProjectProfile.findById( req.params.id,  function( err, project ) {
        project.users.push(req.body.user);
        return project.save( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                console.log( 'Project Users updated' );
                return res.send( project );
            } else {
                console.log( err );
                return res.send('ERROR');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I do that I'm getting the following error

```
{ [ValidationError: Project validation failed]
  message: 'Project validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { 'users.-1._id': 
      { [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "EXAMPLE-STRING" at path "_id"]
        message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "EXAMPLE-STRING" at path "_id"',
        name: 'CastError',
        kind: 'ObjectID',
        value: 'EXAMPLE-STRING',
        path: '_id' } } }
```

Project Schema

```
var ProjectProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projectName: String,
    productName: String,
    users: [{user:'string'}]
});
```

The value EXAMPLE-STRING is a standard string. Does it need a Mongoose _id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you're pushing onto the `project.users` array should be a `User` document (assume that's the name of your model), or it should be an `ObjectId` (or a string representing one) that belongs to a `User` document in your database.

Depending on what `req.body.user` is exactly, this might work:

```
project.users.push(new User(req.body.user));
```

Comment: I didn't have enough detail in my question. I should have been pushing an object instead of a string.